# Retrieve records with unique or largest string in that column which contains other strings in that column and matching count

Tags: sql, group-by, distinct

I have the following table:

`this_table` (phrase is always unique)

| phrase | count |
| --- | --- |
| elemo | 11 |
| e | 37 |
| elemo a | 11 |
| r sundt | 6 |
| wit | 102 |
| lolo m | 102 |
| o | 1475 |
| mo | 111 |
| lo m | 186 |
| domo | 111 |

I'd like a query that removes results if their (*record A*) phrase is contained within another record's (*record B*) phrase AND their (*record A*) count matches the containing record's (*record B*) count.

Results

| phrase | count |
| --- | --- |
| e | 37 |
| elemo a | 11 |
| r sundt | 6 |
| wit | 102 |
| lolo m | 102 |
| o | 1475 |
| lo m | 186 |
| domo | 111 |

Comment: Use a self-join with the condition `LOCATE(t1.phrase, t2.phrase)` to tell if one phrase is a substring of the other.

Comment: I'd like a Ferrari and a LearJet. SO is not a free code writing service. We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself and run into difficulties. When that happens, you can explain the problem, include the sample data and desired output (which you've correctly done here), and the code you've written trying to solve the problem, and ask a specific question about that code, and we'll try to help. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works.

Comment: Projection much? This isn't even a real scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the database, but this should do it. The idea is about the same as suggested by Barmar in the comments. I find it easier to implement the logic using `not exists`

```
with cte (phrase, counts) as
  
(select 'elemo',    11  union all
 select 'e',        37  union all
 select 'elemo a',  11  union all
 select 'r sundt',  6   union all
 select 'wit',     102  union all
 select 'lolo m',  102  union all
 select 'o',       1475 union all
 select 'mo',      111  union all
 select 'lo m',    186  union all
 select 'domo',    111)

select *
from cte a
where not exists (select *
                  from cte b
                  where a.counts=b.counts and 
                        a.phrase <> b.phrase and 
                        a.phrase like concat('%',b.phrase,'%'))
```

Comment: That is a very concise and elegant solution. I wasn't able to find anything like it while trying to solve this on my own. It seems like a technique that isn't commonly used or needed but still has it's place in the arsenal of an SQL master. I'm glad that logic can exist in SQL.